# Cognos results by day_of_week / business days

Tags: report, business-intelligence, cognos

I'm working on a really basic list to retrieve records by date based on current day of the week.

I can't figure out how to get the expression to work correctly.

What I'm trying to accomplish is
Schedule Mon - Friday.

If day_of_week(current_date) = Monday Then get [record date] for prior Friday (Monday pulls Fridays records)

Else If day_of_week(current_date) = Tuesday Then get [record date] for days between Saturday - Monday (Tuesdays pull Sat - Mon records)

Else get [record date] = current_date - 1 (All other business days pull prior days records)

I've tried creating a filter on [record date] based on a query expression [data item1] to get day of week.
day_of_week(current_date,1)

But no luck. Appreciate any help possible. Thanks!

Comment: It would be very much of assistance if you elaborate on the 'no luck' bit.

The structure of your intended filter would be better served as a case rather than if then else.

I'm assuming that where you write Else get [record date] = current_date - 1 you mean to indicate that you have enclosed that current date as a parameter of _day_of_week.

The expression what you have written in the question is what you want to do but not what you've actually have written so I don't know if it is a matter of something as simple as a syntax error, which brings us back to the elaborate on 'no luck'.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It wanted the filter in pure Boolean which I was able to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the data in the database, then compute the date you want the data presented.

Here is a sample filter expression using a brute force method to accomplish this:

```
current_date = 
case
    when _day_of_week ([Sales (query)].[Time].[Date], 1) in (6,7)
        then _add_days ([Sales (query)].[Time].[Date], 9 - _day_of_week ([Sales (query)].[Time].[Date], 1))
    when _day_of_week ([Sales (query)].[Time].[Date], 1) in (5)
        then _add_days ([Sales (query)].[Time].[Date], 3)
    else _add_days([Sales (query)].[Time].[Date], 1)
end
```

You could absolutely use IF-THEN-ELSE for this.  I usually use CASE-WHEN-THEN because I'm usually dealing with SQL databases and it's just easier to do it the same way.

Comment: Thank you. After changing it to pure Boolean I was able to get the result I wanted. This filter worked for me. (( _day_of_week (current_date,1)=1) AND ([Transaction Date]=_add_days (current_date,-3)))

OR

(( _day_of_week (current_date,1)=5) 
AND [Transaction Date] BETWEEN _add_days(current_date,-3) AND _add_days(current_date,-1))

OR

(( _day_of_week (current_date,1) NOT in (1, 2)) AND ([Transaction Date]=_add_days (current_date,-1)))

Comment: I just corrected my answer.  I should have been comparing to the current date, not the current day of the week.